# Dockerfile RUN command mangled. How do I escape it properly?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Using `ubuntu:latest` docker image...

This command works fine at the command line:

```
if [ "`echo hi there`" == "hi there" ]; then echo it worked; else echo nope; fi

root@9df9198ced39:/# if [ "`echo hi there`" == "hi there" ]; then echo it worked; else echo nope; fi
it worked
```

But in a Dockerfile `RUN` command, it doesn't:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN if [ "`echo hi there`" == "hi there" ]; then echo it worked; else echo nope; fi

sh: 1: [: hi there: unexpected operator
```

I've tried escaping `"`, `backtick`, `[` & `]`.  I've tried using `# escape=\`... I've tried JSON syntax:

```
RUN ["sh", "-c", "if [ \"`echo hi there`\" == \"hi there\" ]; then echo it worked; else echo nope; fi"]
```

...Just can't seem to find the right way to do it.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I generally avoid trying to embed entire shell scripts like this into a `RUN` statement. Just put your script in a file, `COPY` it into the image, and then `RUN sh /path/to/your/script.sh`. This avoids all sorts of issues around escaping, multi-line scripts, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use '=' and not '=='

The reason you get different results maybe because of different shell interpreters.

```
$ bash
$ if [ "`echo hi there`" = "hi there" ]; then echo it worked; else echo nope; fi
it worked
$ if [ "`echo hi there`" == "hi there" ]; then echo it worked; else echo nope; fi
it worked

$ sh
$ if [ "`echo hi there`" = "hi there" ]; then echo it worked; else echo nope; fi
it worked
$ if [ "`echo hi there`" == "hi there" ]; then echo it worked; else echo nope; fi
sh: 2: [: hi there: unexpected operator
```